# How to mathematically describe the process of spacetime curvature?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I guess as a result of the energy-momentum tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$ coupling to a flat Minkowski metric, $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, the flat metric can become that of a curved spacetime, $g_{\mu\nu}$. How can one describe this process mathematically?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations

Comment: Curvature is not a process. It is a local property of the spacetime manifold.

Comment: I guess my question wasn't too clear. What I meant was how exactly the energy-momentum tensor couples to the metric which as a result the metric changes.

Comment: Given an energy-momentum tensor, you solve the Einstein field equations for the metric. This is how you get black holes, Big Bang, gravitational waves, etc.

Comment: I do know that but I was hoping for something that explains the actual lagrangian of the coupling of energy momentum tensor to the metric.

Comment: I believe calling it a coupling is incorrect except when dealong with linearized GR.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein–Hilbert_action) is the action for GR.

Comment: [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/581337/how-does-one-add-matter-coupling-terms-to-the-linearized-lagrangian-for-general) is the linearized coupling $\mathcal{L}_{\text{int}} \sim h_{\mu\nu}T^{\mu\nu}$.